# @Inject outside Angular2 application

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

Is it possible to retrieve any `@Injectable` like:

```
var config = @Inject(Config);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get new instances from dependency injection, you need a reference to the [Injector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Injector-class.html) then you can acquire new instances with

```
injector.get(Config);
```

How you can get a reference to `Injector` depends on where your code is.
In an Angular component or service, just inject it

```
constructor(private injector:Injector) {}
```

You can also just create your own injector like

```
var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([Car, Engine]);
```

where `Car` and `Engine` are the providers the injector can create instances for.

To get the injector of your Angular application to be used outside your Angular application you can use

Example from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572

```
let appInjectorRef: Injector;
export const appInjector = (injector?: Injector):Injector => {
    if (injector) {
      appInjectorRef = injector;
    }

    return appInjectorRef;
};

bootstrap(App, [
  Auth,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  Car,
  Engine
]).then((appRef: ComponentRef) => {
  // store a reference to the application injector
  appInjector(appRef.injector);
});

let injector: Injector = appInjector();
injector.get(Car);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to declare `injector` as a global variable so I could use it a bit easier.

In the file where you bootstrap angular:

```js
declare global {
    var injector: Injector;
}

bootstrap(/* your bootstrap stuff */).then((appRef) => {
    injector = appRef.injector;
});
```

The above will give you access to an `injector` variable anywhere else in your code.

In the file where you need an instance of `Config`:

```js
import { Config } from './path/to/config.service';

class TestClass {
    private config: Config;

    constructor() {
        this.config = injector.get(Config);
    }
}
```